# wordpress how to call function within class

Tags: wordpress

**wp-content/plugins/yith/closs.yith.php** has the following code :

if ( ! class_exists ( 'YITH_WooCommerce_Question_Answer' ) ) {
    class YITH_WooCommerce_Question_Answer {
    function love(){
                echo "kkkk";
            }
    }
    }

how to call the love() function that within a class from other page ?
I tried write the following codes in **wp-content/themes/xtocky/woocommerce/content-product.php** :

```
$som_var = new YITH_WooCommerce_Question_Answer();
$som_var->love();
```

but not working...

And then i tried :

```
YITH_WooCommerce_Question_Answer::love();
```

It is not working too.

Comment: your function is correct where you put this code. please put this YITH_WooCommerce_Question_Answer class in theme functions.php and try to add this in $som_var = new YITH_WooCommerce_Question_Answer();
$som_var->love(); header.php for test.

Comment: What do you mean not working? Do you get any error message?

Comment: Hey, when we create a class we need an object to call class properties. Here $som_var = new YITH_WooCommerce_Question_Answer();., this will work. but YITH_WooCommerce_Question_Answer::love(); will not work because the function non static.

Comment: @Corlax function and class save in plugins folder.
I wrote my code in theme folder to call the function from plugins folder (not in theme folder). It mean my code and the function code are in difference folder.

Comment: @vaso123
I dont see any error message on my page, but my page keep loading, cannot finish loaded. And I press ctrl + f12 on chrome see error "Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).tipTip is not a function" on console.

Comment: i tried to wrote my own class and function in plugins folder to test call them and success, hmm ... maybe original class YITH_WooCommerce_Question_Answer has some other code to prevent the call, let me check where is the code to prevent call... will update here.